# Screenshot And video option is missing in Android Studio 3.4.1?

Tags: android-studio, screenshot

Android studio missing take screenshot and video option is missing in latest version(3.4.1).

**Ctrl+s** is working but i am unable to get screenshot in real device(attached via cable) use **Ctrl+s**.

Any other way to taking the screenshot of real device and store in to system?

[image]

Comment: please restart android studio.

Comment: if restart doesn't work then reinstall it.

Comment: go to Window-> Restore default layout. Try and see if it restores your Android studio layout to default ones

Comment: @earthling i already installed latest version of android studio

Comment: @VedprakashWagh its not working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click on setting icon on top and click "Show Toolbar" like in below pic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can take photos/videos under Logcat, using these buttons. Sometimes they are hidden in a little drop down, which is indicated by two little arrows instead.

Unless you mean taking screenshots and saving them on the device. In which case just use the device's mechanism for taking screenshots?

Comment: No that buttons not hidden.
No i don't want to store that screenshot in device.

Comment: by those buttons screenshot will not be saved on your device. Instead it will save in your pc or laptop.

Comment: yes yes i want to store in to PC or LAPTOP not in real device

Comment: Ok, so then try the above. Did it work? Do you need more help?

Comment: Sorry didnt see you edited the question. That is super weird, I have the same version of Android Studio and it seems fine :(